# Is this protection circuit designed properly?

Tags: diodes, circuit-protection, circuit-design, reverse-polarity

I designed this protection circuit to avoid reverse polarity and over-voltage.

Here is the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJRuk5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is the circuit designed correctly?

Specifications:

conditions:
$$-20<V_{in}<20$$

requirements:

$$
\text{if }\  0< V_{in} <15  \qquad \text{then }\  V_{out}\approx V_{in} \\   
\text{if }\  15< V_{in} <20 \qquad \text{then }\  V_{out}=15 \ \text{and } \color{Red}{LED } \text{ will light.}\ \\
\text{if }\  -20< V_{in} <0 \qquad \text{then }\  V_{out}=0 \ \text{and } \color{Yellow}{LED } \text{ will light.}\   
$$

Comment: If you have input over-voltage above ~17 V, you need some idea what the source current capability might be in order to size your zener diodes.

Comment: In that case, at around 16.3V one or both of D4 & D6 will burn up.

Comment: In order to understand if this circuit is suitable, you need to put a full specification on input and output voltages with the output current requirements.

Comment: I suggest that you ditch all the LEDs. LIghts everywhere are just annoying, adds complexity and takes up space.

Comment: You may have a (short lived?) overvoltage *indicator*, but you do not have overvoltage *protection* unless some series element or the supply itself has a lower *actual* current limit than the zeners.  You could consider adding some sort of fuse rated for a lower current than the zeners can handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you didn't see is that with 20V applied minus the volt drop of the 1N5819 (leaving maybe 19.3 volts), there will be 19.3 volts applied across two series zeners that don't want a terminal voltage greater than 16.6 volts. This will equal smoke.

The other thing is the an LED might have a forward volt drop of 1.5 volts before it starts glowing and, with below 14.5 volts (plus the forward volt drop of the 1N5819) applied at the input your red LED won't light.

You should also put a bleed resistor across the yellow LED to prevent it getting reverse biased when off - check its spec - it probably has a max reverse voltage under 10V - you can't 100% relay in the 1N4007 for doing this.

---

EDIT SECTION

You could use the LTC4367 - 100V Overvoltage, Undervoltage and Reverse Supply Protection Controller. It's programmable with resistors to set at which point the over-voltage circuit begins. Here's a typical 24v example: -

[image]
[image]

If you don't want to use this at least look at the depth of the specifications regarding what happens when O-V and U-V kick-in. There isn't a biblical amount to write down or consider but there's a lot more than you have done so far.

By the way, it's unreasonable to expect the output to be 15V with inputs that range from 15V to 20V - there will be a volt drop BUT, if you are prepared to attach a buck boost regulator to the output of the above chip then you should be in business and you could get 15V out with the input at 10V.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel - this is an under-constrained design - we cannot second guess what can or can't be done without you being more objective on what you want to achieve.

Comment: An alternative to Andy's second paragraph is to place a diode in reverse parallel to protect the LED. This will shunt any reverse leakage from D1 around D2 and limit reverse voltage to 0.6 V or so.

Comment: @Andyaka. Can you put the right schematic in your answer. I also added the voltage specifications.

Comment: I'm not a free design service - think about this if Vout max is 15 volts then Vin max cannot be greater than about 15.6 volts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need D6 at all but a respectable dissipation resistor in the 220-330 ohm range to maintain D4 in avalanche, the led will begin glowing at 12.8 V.

Answer (score 0):

This will save some components and behave nearly identically. The trick is to recognize that you can forward bias a zener (it'll look like a 0.6 V diode), and putting 2 back-back LEDs allows one to protect the other.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRpzgD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that (just like your original), it will take 0.6 V + 2.1  = 2.7 V reverse V for the yellow LED to light. Using Red for reverse may be better because those LEDs are ~ 1.7 V. If you use a PNP transistor together with the zener, it is possible to eliminate the 0.6 V from the diode, thus a red LED would begin to light at -1.7 V

Comment: How does this circuit limit the max input voltage of 20V to less than 15 volts at the output?

Comment: @BlueSky - you are missing the point - add up the voltages and you have to conclude that with 20V at the input the 3V3 or the 11V zener will fry. Now that is a free design service!

Comment: It's becoming a mess and me and @daniel are encouraging you to produce a full spec. This means what range of input voltages it's meant to work at and what range of output voltages are acceptable for that range of input voltages. Not just this but loading values and sourcing currents. Not just a few words - it takes time. I have to say I don't understand your full requirements and I'm not going to spend a lot of time helping you thru this, you have to think about this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to put 2 schematics in 1 answer -- this is my original:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQLh6p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The same problem like you other answer. If v_in is greater than 15V, zeners will burn.